# Toggle (Checkbox) Button in TableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I'm new to iOS dev and I've been trying to toggle a button/checkbox in my tableviewcell by tapping the cell. My code is pretty naive, switching to the 'check' image works fine, but the issue is switching back to un-checked image when double tapping the cell.

What's not working in my code? Also is there a better way to do this? (perhaps via delegate funcs from the cell itself?)

Code examples would be very helpful! Thanks.

```
var isChecked:Bool = true
```

This following func is called in didSelectRowAtIndexPath func in my Tableview class.

```
let btnCheckBox:UIButton = cell.contactCheckbox
setState(button: btnCheckBox)


func setState(button: UIButton){

    let check = UIImage(named: "check_green")
    let unCheck = UIImage(named: "un_check_green")

    if isChecked {
        button.setImage(check, for: .normal)
        isChecked = false
        print("First Tap - Bool is \(isChecked)")
    } else {
        button.setImage(unCheck, for: .normal)
        isChecked = true
        print("Double Tap - Bool is \(isChecked)")

    }
}
```

Comment: Perform print statements in each method that is supposed to be called so you get a sense of what is happening when you tap on each cells.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIButton , and set image for state of button, sample
check_green for selected
check_red for none
And each UITableviewcell must have an isSelected

Comment: swapped to UIButton and I'm getting the same issue.
'checking' works fine, but switching back to 'unChecked' is the problem.

Comment: I edited the code sample. there is really nothing else to show in my tableview class, the func is called via the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. the 'cell' is a customCell class, which contains the checkBox outlet of type UIButton.